# Adaptive streaming doesn't work

Tags: uwp

I copied the code verbatim from [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming), namely adding

```
System.Uri manifestUri = new Uri("http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/49b57c87-f5f3-48b3-ba22-c55cfdffa9cb/Sintel.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)");
mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(manifestUri);
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

to my page and

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>
```

to my XAML. However, when running, there is no playback the error reported is

**Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path.**

I have no idea why there is such error considering this is official example given by Microsoft and that Edge can play the video perfectly upon pasting the URL. Apparently, the app can play the audio perfectly if I give it an audio file in assets by changing

```
System.Uri manifestUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/sample.mp3");
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The code you've posted works well in my side. Have you tested in any other device? Did they have the same issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT You're right. I did development on a RS2 preview build of Windows and Visual Studio 2017 RC. Just as I got access to a RS1 machine and VS2015, it works.